# How to update QupZilla on Ubuntu Mate?

Tags: ubuntu, web-browsers, software-compilation

[image: QupZilla] The lightweight browser [QupZilla](https://www.qupzilla.com/) is fairly outdated on [Ubuntu Mate](https://ubuntu-mate.org/raspberry-pi/).

I wonder how I can update/compile QupZilla from source?

Upstream, there is [no ARM package available for download](https://www.qupzilla.com/download).

Comment: Instead of compiling a significant number of custom packages, I ended up using [qutebrowser](http://qutebrowser.org) to my great delight. If one is somewhat accustomed to the [`vim` text editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vim_(text_editor)), this is the most superb web browser around!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build it from source, follow these steps (as root):

Download source of the latest version. (For now it is v2.0.1)

```
# wget https://github.com/QupZilla/qupzilla/archive/v2.0.1.tar.gz
```

Extract the zipped archive and enter into the source directory.

```
# tar xvf v2.0.1.tar.gz
# cd qupzilla-2.0.1
```

Read `BUILD.md` for important points. For example, it says that `Qt 5 (>= 5.6)` is required.

```
# more BUILD.md
```

**Amendment #1 - Start**

The highest version in Ubuntu Mate repo is `Qt 5.5.1` as the question owner says below.

Build `Qt 5` having version equal or higher than `Qt 5.6` as described at [Qt for Linux/X11 - Build from Source](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/linux-building.html). Be sure that **you have enough space** to compile Qt from source. Here is [the link to source of Qt 5.7](http://ftp.fau.de/qtproject/archive/qt/5.7/5.7.0/single/qt-everywhere-opensource-src-5.7.0.tar.gz).

**Amendment #1 - End**

Set installation path `QUPZILLA_PREFIX` to whatever you want. The default prefix is /usr. Detailed explanations about this configuration and about many others can be found in `BUILD.md`.

```
# export QUPZILLA_PREFIX=/opt/qupzilla-2.0.1
```

Compile and install. Some dependencies may be missing on the system. They can be easily installed with `apt-get`.

```
# qmake
# make
# make install
```

After successful make and install, the browser binary can be found under `/opt/qupzilla-2.0.1/bin`.

Comment: Close, but no cigar! `Project ERROR: QupZilla requires at least Qt 5.6!` and Ubuntu Mate is still on `5.5.1`.

Comment: @SergeStroobandt, you can check the updated answer. By the way, it is written in your profile that your home is **GNU/Linux-only**. So, I have expected you to know something about compilation.

Comment: I tend to keep my machines as vanilla as possible for easy maintenance… In the mean time, I tested out Qupzilla 2.0.1 on [Manjaro ARM](http://manjaro-arm.org/), only to notice that it has become very resource hungry.